# Autoload PHP library in PrestaShop for shipping carrier module

Tags: php, composer-php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I want to use this library in PrestaShop shipping carrier modules: https://github.com/dvdoug/BoxPacker

The BoxPacker library determines the number and size of boxes required from an available list to pack the selected items. I will use the library in shipping carrier modules, such as fedexcarrier, to retrieve more accurate shipping rates. The library uses namespace and is PSR-4 compliant.

I don't know how to integrate it with PrestaShop v1.5.6.2. How can I integrate the library with PrestaShop (using composer?) and make it available in the shipping modules using PrestaShop's autoloader?

Comment: what version of prestashop you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to clone the specific shipping module and add this feature just the way you would add it in a custom script. There's nothing special in PrestaShop or any other script regarding such integration. You need to include the class files where they are required explicitly.

For example if you use this classes within the main module file, you need to include them before the class declaration.

Comment: I thought I might add it to the classes folder and have it autoloaded. Is that wrong? Why should I clone the shipping module? Better to not modify the existing? So I would have BoxPacker duplicated in multiple modules?

Comment: You should clone the module, because on the next upgrade all your custom changes will be overridden by the new version. Also it's good every module to have it's how version of the 3rd party library and to include it where it is needed. Only the specific module will use them after all, they are not common for the whole store. These files are not part of PrestaShop so their place is not in the classes folder. This is just how the things must be done.